# Keyboard without Windows logo?

Tags: linux, keyboard

Ten years ago I bought a Cherry Linux keyboard which has an image of Tux the penguin in place of the Windows logo on the "Windows" key. But it's getting old and dirty now, and one of the tilt supports just broke. So I am looking for a new keyboard to replace it, but there's one condition that doesn't seem to be available. I don't want the "Windows" key to show the Windows logo. I would prefer it to show some other symbol, preferably Tux the penguin. The actual key can, and should, still be there, it just should have a different picture on it. I have searched over and over on Google for it but just can't seem to find one that's available any more. Do such keyboards still exist?

Answer (score 2):

Find a keyboard that can use replaceable key caps and use one of these

https://www.keyboardco.com/product/tux-penguin-logo-windows-keys-2-keycaps-for-cherry-mx-switches.asp

That will work for because you will be replacing the WIN key cap with the TUX cap but the functionality remains the same.